# Cannot make PHP variable option in <select> tag html

Tags: php, html

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [denumireObiect] => Telefon ) 
    [1] => Array ( [denumireObiect] => Laptop ) 
    [2] => Array ( [denumireObiect] => Tableta ) 
    [3] => Array ( [denumireObiect] => Obiect ) 
)
```

I am trying to take all of those words and make them options for a `<select>` tag.

This is the code I am using for that:

```
foreach ($result as $i) {
            echo '<option value = ', $result[$i],'>', $result[$i], '</option>';
          }
```

This paragraph gives me `Illegal offset type` error.

This is a `var_dump($result)` result.

```
array(4) { 
[0]=> array(1) { 
["denumireObiect"]=> string(7) "Telefon" 
} 

[1]=> array(1) 
{ ["denumireObiect"]=> string(6) "Laptop" } 

[2]=> array(1) {
["denumireObiect"]=> string(7) "Tableta" 
} 

[3]=> array(1) {
["denumireObiect"]=> string(6) "Obiect" } 
} 
...
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried doing it like this:

```
foreach ($result as $i => $val) {
        echo '<option value = ', $i,'>', $i, '</option>';
      }
```

and it returns `0, 1, 2, 3`

**Any help is appreciated!**

Comment: is $result the array you mentioned and could you please provide a var_dump($result)? In your foreach you should be abled to access $i without referencing the $result array. But without knowing $result und $i I can not tell you how exactly

Comment: @j4g0 I have edited the post. added a `var_dump` result and tried a new way to do this. Hope it helps!

Comment: I have what feels like a very dumb question, but it might be an internationalization thing... does using `,` as a string concatenator work? AFAIK you need to use `.` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), but maybe that's because I'm in the US. `echo "test","ing";` vs `echo "test"."ing";` - I would expect the first to throw an error, while the second would output `testing`.

Comment: i do not think it is concatenating but rather one echo outputting several strings. It threw me off at first, too :D

Comment: whoa, TIL. I had no idea you could list things like that to be echoed. Sure enough, it's documented on the `echo` page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@WOUNDEDStevenJones made a good point. I have updated my code to make it more readable. Note that you would have to rename the $result variable to $results.

Since every `$result` from your code is an associative array with the same `"denumireObiect"` key, you could get the values like this:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo "<option value=\"{$result['denumireObiect']}\">{$result['denumireObiect']}</option>";
}
```

If you do not like using the interpolation you could reformat the echo statement like this:

```
echo '<option value="' . $result['denumireObiect'] . '">' . $result['denumireObiect'] . '</option>';
```

or use your format from before :)

Comment: This gives me `Trying to access array offset on value of type int` error.

Comment: I removed the => $val from the foreach, we do not need it

Comment: To be more clear, `$i` is usually used as the index counter in loops (i.e. `for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++)`) so I would recommend keeping this style and either writing `foreach ($result as $i => $val)` and then using `$val['denumireObiect']` in the loop (or `$result[$i]['denumireObiect']`, but that seems unnecessarily silly in this case). This way, `$i` is essentially still an index counter, which is about the only thing single character variable names should be used for.